# Reload image in MapInfo

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I have a mbx that creates a layout. The layout consist of a number of .wmf pictures and ofcource a map. During the execution I create .Tab files that reference to the pictures looking like:

```
Definition Table
  File "picture.wmf"
  Type "RASTER"
  (0,1) (0,0) Label "Pkt 1",
  (1,1) (1,0) Label "Pkt 2",
  (0,0) (0,1) Label "Pkt 3"
  CoordSys NonEarth Units "ft"
  Units "ft"
```

When something is changed and I make a new layout some pictures are updated and overwriten with new ones. The .Tab files is still the same. The problem is that it's the old pictures that shows up in the layout. When I open the pictures direkt in my filesystem it shows the new one. I think MapInfo caches the old picture in some way and wonder if there is a way to reload the .Tab file or in some way to make MapInfo understand that the information that the .tab file refers to is updated?

Comment: In this process once you have updated the tab file with the new image location/name, do you close and then reopen the tab file?